# Repeated looping of if/else statements in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with repeated loops through if/else statements in an onclick function. It's a game where you have to say whether a word is valid or not and you keep going until you get one wrong.

What is happening though is the code goes through a branch of the if/else the same number of times as the questions you've done. So the first question once, second question twice and so on. So on the fifth question you'll get 5 alert boxes, and your score will increment by 5 instead of 1.

It is quite a long bit of code in total, which works otherwise (I've not done the hi-score bit yet) otherwise. I've put a shortened bit of it below where I think the problem must be.

The full thing is on http://www.absp.org.uk/test/study3lw.shtml

```
function quiz(){

...

    $('#true').on('click', function(){
        ...
        if (valid === true){          // ie got it right
            score++;
            alert(score);
            ...
        } else {                      // got it wrong
            ...
            score = 0;
            $('#word').append("*");
            alert("Game Over!");
        }
    });

    $('#false').on('click', function(){
        ...
        if (valid === false){         // ie got it right
            score++;
            alert(score);
            ...
        } else {                      // got it wrong
            score = 0;
            alert("Game Over!");
            ...
        }
    });

}


$('#start').on('click', function (){  // calls the above for each question
    ...
    quiz();
});
```

Comment: You should add the event listeners outside of `quiz()` since you only need to add them once.

Comment: Yea seems to work, just have to rewrite a lot of it now with closures etc. Ugh.

Comment: It would probably help to use object oriented programming for this,  but that would still take a lot of rewriting, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a new click event for each question, so by the fifth question, you have five event listeners for your buttons. I believe jQuery has .one() that will de-register the event after it's fired. Try using .one() instead of .on()

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: That partially works. If I change the $('#start').on .... to .one it will work once and that's it. If I leave that alone and change the true and false .on bits then it works better but it still queues up the other. For instance if I click true 3 times in a row, then click false it will run it 4 times. 

I think I need to either rewrite it so I wrap the true and false bits into one function which covers either event occurring, and use the .one handler. Or find some way of ending the current event handler when it reaches the end of the function. Neither of which I know how to do.